# How do I use OpenCover and ReportGenerator to view Unit Test Coverage Results?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, nuget-package, opencover, reportgenerator

I'm a noob to using both OpenCover and ReportGenerator and I'm struggling a bit in understanding how to get them working. I'm using VS.NET 2012 'Professional' which means I don't have access to the built in unit test coverage tooling. I also have ReSharper installed, but don't want to pay for another utility in 'dotCover'

It looks like OpenCover and ReportGenerator will do what I need and I see the documentation that was downloaded alongside, but am missing some understanding. 1st off, when I download the nuget packges for both, what should my target project be? I have a multi layer app, so I'm assuming my unit test project correct, or does it even matter? I see in the documentation, I'm just pointing at the /bin (I think) of a solution using command line commands, so maybe I didn't even need to add these downloads to any particular project (could have been a test harness). Can someone tell me if I have this correct?

Once I have them installed, I'm trying to get unit test coverage metrics, and the docs that came with the package are not as clear as I hoped. Are there any good blog posts or links that walk through using these tool together to get the metrics?

Comment: I must add to this that OpenCover has one of the worst documentations ever!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

you do not need to add these to particular project

I use report generator and open cover to generate test coverage results too. This is the script I use to generate the codecoverage using opencover

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenCover\OpenCover.Console.exe" -register:user -target:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe" -targetargs:"/noisolation /testcontainer:\"C:\<your project path>\bin\Debug\<project name>.dll\" /resultsfile:C:\Reports\MSTest\<project name>.trx" -filter:"+[*]*" -mergebyhash -output:C:\Reports\MSTest\projectCoverageReport.xml
```

Note that if your argument needs to escape quotes i.e. to pass arguments with spaces to that target process then you can use `"`, e.g.: `-targetargs:"c:\program files"`

This is the script I use to run report generator.

```
C:\ReportGenerator\bin\ReportGenerator.exe -reports:"C:\Reports\MSTest\\projectCoverageReport.xml" -targetdir:"C:\Reports\CodeCoverage"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is <your project path> and <project name> for the test project or main project?

Answer (score 16):

After several years of using these open source tools, I finally created a comprehensive post on how to use OpenCover and ReportCover to generate unit test coverage metrics.

The post describes how to create the `.bat` file and the commands needed to do the following:

- Generate an output report of unit test metrics using OpenCover
- Generating a `.htm` report using ReportGenerator
- Analyzing the output data to interpret unit test coverage metrics

[Using OpenCover and ReportGenerator to get Unit Testing Code Coverage Metrics in .NET](http://www.allenconway.net/2015/06/using-opencover-and-reportgenerator-to.html)

Answer (score 5):

Thanks @atconway for your tutorial.
I've updated your .bat script a little, to ease future upgrades, and project changes.

Summarizing, to use OpenCover with NUnit you have to add to your project these nugets:

- OpenCover
- NUnit.ConsoleRunner
- ReportGenerator by Daniel Palme

and here is updated .bat file. 
To run it just edit "settings" and save script as .bat file in root of your project.

```
@echo off
REM ** Be sure to install these nugets:
REM ** NUnit.ConsoleRunner
REM ** OpenCover
REM ** ReportGenerator
REM **
REM ** All paths should be entered without quotes

REM ** SET TestResultsFileProjectName=CalculatorResults
SET TestResultsFileProjectName=<ANY_NAME>

REM ** SET DLLToTestRelativePath=Calculator\bin\Debug\MyCalc.dll
SET DLLToTestRelativePath=<VALID_PATH>

REM ** Filters Wiki https://github.com/opencover/opencover/wiki/Usage
REM ** SET Filters=+[Calculator]* -[Calculator]CalculatorTests.*
SET Filters=<VALID_FILTERS>

SET OpenCoverFolderName=OpenCover.4.6.519
SET NUnitConsoleRunnerFolderName=NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.6.1
SET ReportGeneratorFolderName=ReportGenerator.2.5.6

REM *****************************************************************

REM Create a 'GeneratedReports' folder if it does not exist
if not exist "%~dp0GeneratedReports" mkdir "%~dp0GeneratedReports"

REM Remove any previous test execution files to prevent issues overwriting
IF EXIST "%~dp0%TestResultsFileProjectName%.trx" del "%~dp0%TestResultsFileProjectName%.trx%"

REM Remove any previously created test output directories
CD %~dp0
FOR /D /R %%X IN (%USERNAME%*) DO RD /S /Q "%%X"

REM Run the tests against the targeted output
call :RunOpenCoverUnitTestMetrics

REM Generate the report output based on the test results
if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
 call :RunReportGeneratorOutput
)

REM Launch the report
if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
 call :RunLaunchReport
)
exit /b %errorlevel%

:RunOpenCoverUnitTestMetrics
"%~dp0packages\%OpenCoverFolderName%\tools\OpenCover.Console.exe" ^
-register:user ^
-target:"%~dp0packages\%NUnitConsoleRunnerFolderName%\tools\nunit3-console.exe" ^
-targetargs:"--noheader \"%~dp0%DLLToTestRelativePath%\"" ^
-filter:"%Filters%" ^
-mergebyhash ^
-skipautoprops ^
-excludebyattribute:"System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute" ^
-output:"%~dp0GeneratedReports\%TestResultsFileProjectName%.xml"
exit /b %errorlevel%

:RunReportGeneratorOutput
"%~dp0packages\%ReportGeneratorFolderName%\tools\ReportGenerator.exe" ^
-reports:"%~dp0GeneratedReports\%TestResultsFileProjectName%.xml" ^
-targetdir:"%~dp0GeneratedReports\ReportGenerator Output"
exit /b %errorlevel%

:RunLaunchReport
start "report" "%~dp0GeneratedReports\ReportGenerator Output\index.htm"
exit /b %errorlevel%
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a hell to configure opencover for multiple test containers.

Use this my smart Powershell script, it can give you some ideas.

https://github.com/rpokrovskij/opencover4vs.ps1/blob/master/opencover4vs.ps1

you need to configure two major things : how to find your test dlls and which namespaces to include to the output. I do it this way:

```
$TestDllsPatterns = @(,'*\bin\Debug\Vse.*.Test.dll')  
$TestableCodeNamespacePatterns = @(,'*')
```

Note, my tests starts from prefix Vse. You need the `Debug\Prefix` key to filter out core nUnit tests from folders like `Debug\netcore1.1\Vse`.

Answer (score 0):

I had to install OpenCover from msi or chocolatey package because when I try to run OpenCover command using the Nugget package executable throws the following error:

> Committing... No results, this could be for a number of reasons. The
> most common reasons are:
> 1) missing PDBs for the assemblies that match the filter please review the
> output file and refer to the Usage guide (Usage.rtf) about filters.
> 2) the profiler may not be registered correctly, please refer to the Usage
> guide and the -register switch.