# When I run the coverage tests, I get the coverage of the code of the tests methods, no the coverage of the methods that I want to test

Tags: c#, code-coverage, mstest, opencover

I have a project with classes and methods that I want to test. I have another project with the test methods that will test the methods of my main project.

I run the tests with opencover and I generate the reports with reportgenerator, with this commands that I have in a .bet file:

```
..\tools\OpenCover.Console.exe -register:user -target:"C:\myDllWithTests.dll" -output:"c:\coverage\opencovertests.xml"

.\ReportGenerator.exe "-reports:c:\coverage\opencovertests.xml" "-targetdir:c:\coverage\opencovertests.xml\reports"
```

I am using MSTest for testing.

The problem is that in the html report, I see that the code that is covered is the tests methods, not the methods in my test main project.

How I could add the main methods in the result?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `target` argument for OpenCover pass the path to MSTest (e.g. "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe") and specify your test assemblies (e.g. "C:\myDllWithTests.dll") in `targetargs` argument.

To remove test assemblies from code coverage statistics, specify them in [filter argument](https://github.com/opencover/opencover/wiki/Usage#understanding-filters).

Below is OpenCover command that works fine for me. Here code under test is placed in SampleApp.dll and test code is placed in SampleApp.Tests.dll.

```
.\OpenCover.Console.exe -register:user -mergebyhash -target:"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe" -targetargs:"/testcontainer:\"d:\test\SampleApp\SampleApp.Tests\bin\Debug\SampleApp.Tests.dll\"" -output:UTResults.xml -filter:"+[SampleApp*]* -[SampleApp.Tests]*"
```

Result report contains only stats for SampleApp.dll assembly, SampleApp.Tests.dll is excluded:

[image]

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16615611/5740031) for some more details.
There is also a [great article](http://www.allenconway.net/2015/06/using-opencover-and-reportgenerator-to.html) by Allen Conway on using OpenCover & ReportGenerator for .Net projects.

Comment: I tried adding the targetargs, but the result is the same. About the article, I knew it, but he didn't offer the source code, and I have the doubt if the tests are in the same dll than the main code or is anothe different dll. Beucause in my case the problem is that I only get the coverage of the test assembly and not of the main assembly.

Comment: I have tried with this filter: -filter:"+[\*]\* -[\*Tests]\*" -mergebyhash but it doesn't include the main.dll that is in the same folder than the test.dll. Also I have tried with the complete name of the main dll and still it doesn't work.

Comment: May be the problem is not with OpenCover, but with the tests itself. What is the output of MSTest? Do you see stats on executed tests, e.g. "1/1 test(s) Passed"?

Comment: Yes, I can see the name of the tests that are run and the number that are passed and the number that are not passed.

Comment: I am thinking, opencover is compatible with .net standard?

Comment: I am sure that opencover is not compatible with .net standard yet. I have try the same with a .net framework project and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This might be quite a late answer here, but I've spent an hour or two playing with this and found the following will fix this. It's worth noting that I had the original bat script from another project that I know works, and just changed the DLL file name, so I know the script was OK.

The additional check to make is to:-

1. Right click the project that has the source code you want visible in the coverage report (not the unit test project) and click **Properties**
2. Select **Build** > **Output** > **Advanced**
3. Set **Debugging information** to **Full**
4. Rebuild solution and re-run bat file.

Works for me in Visual Studio 2019 with .NET Framework 4.7.2 projects.